# Custom SQL GROUP BY Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a very customized SQL query that I am having problems implementing.  I am using SQL-Server-2008.

I have only one table in this query, but I am looking for very specific data.  The requirements for this query are:

For each DISTINCT PartNumber (column), I need to select the NEWEST (max) PO (column) to be selected.  However, there is another column named "Receipt" where if it contains a value at all, then the PartNumber should be excluded all together.

I am somewhat familiar with GROUP BY clauses and CASES for selections, but I'm not sure how to tie all I know together into one working query...

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance =).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Partnumber, MAX(PO)
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable
                  WHERE (Receipt <> '0'
                         OR Receipt <> '')
                  AND Partnumber = t1.partnumber)
GROUP BY PartNumber
```

The `NOT EXISTS` here will exclude any row that has a partnumber for which a receipt is populated anywhere in the table.

Comment: This seems to be the best approach.  Works for me!  Disregard the previous edit of this comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @ImGreg - I added that in.  You could also use `NOT IN` but that has issues with `NULL` as Aaron points out in comments on the other answers.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!  The PartNumber 'should' never be null, but best play it safe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Anti-Join option

```
SELECT t1.Partnumber, MAX(t1.PO)
FROM MyTable t1
     LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT PartNumber From MyTable
       WHERE  COALESCE(Receipt, '') = '') t2
     ON t1.Partnumber = t2.Partnumber
WHERE
     t2.Partnumber is null
GROUP BY t1.PartNumber
```

Comment: Im not sure about the 'WHERE' clause for PartNumber being null?  But this seems right other than that.

Comment: @ImGreg - that excludes records that meet the `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(PO)
FROM aTable
WHERE PartNumber NOT IN (
   SELECT PartNumber
   FROM aTable
   WHERE Receipt IS NULL
   GROUP BY PartNumber
   HAVING PartNumber IS NOT NULL /* fix */
)
GROUP BY PartNumber
```

Comment: Suggest against `NOT IN`. While in this case it may be implied/assumed that PartNumber is not nullable, this query can return unpredictable results if PartNumber is nullable (which may be true for other readers looking at solutions to their own, slightly different problem). Suggest `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN` constructs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Based on clarification in comments, this simplifies to:

If I understand you correctly, this should do it:

```
SELECT MAX(PO)
FROM Table
GROUP BY PartNumber
HAVING MAX(Receipt) = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause will eliminate any `PartNumber` where there is even a single non-zero `Receipt` entry for any rows with that `PartNumber`.

Comment: I would only add Receipt <> ' ' as if its a field where it may have been populated, but then blanked out, the NULL might no longer be applicable and should be excluded...  I would also include the partNumber in the field list in case they need to look them up in logical "groups" vs staggered by some random, unrelated P/O number basis.

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what he wants - he wants to exclude `Partnumber`s that have a populated receipt.  Also,**`MAX(Receipt)` WILL NEVER BE NULL** since `NULL` is ignored by aggregates by default

Comment: Thanks, I was already in the process of correcting the sense of the test.  `NULL` does get ignored by aggregates, but if there are no non-`NULL` `Receipt` fields the result of `MAX(Receipt)` is actually `NULL` and can be tested as such.

Comment: And it's still the opposite of what he is after

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned the Receipt column will be '0' not a null value if it is empty.  Also, doesn't this only check the max value of the receipt column?

Comment: @JNK: Have you tried it?  `declare @test table (partnumber int, po int, receipt int)

insert into @test (partnumber, po, receipt)
values 
(2, 1, NULL),
(2, 2, NULL),
(2, 3, NULL),
(1, 1, NULL),
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 3, NULL)

SELECT PartNumber, MAX(PO), MAX(Receipt)
FROM @test
GROUP BY PartNumber
HAVING MAX(Receipt) IS NULL`

Comment: @ImGreg: Fixed this up based on the information that the Receipt column could be zero.  This actually simplifies it quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.  Shouldn't it also be `MAX(receipt)` not `MIN`?  `MIN` will be any row that has any value of 0 for receipt.  He wants to include only partnumbers that have only 0 values.

Comment: @JNK: You are correct, thanks!  Haste (and too many quick edits) makes waste.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(Receipt, 0)) = 0`?