# SQL Custom Grouping and Selection Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I recently asked this question here and got some great answers! 
[Custom SQL GROUP BY Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023314/custom-sql-group-by-clause)

However, it turns out I provided the wrong requirements for my problem.  Sorry guys!

Sooooo.  What I need to select is:

Distinct values in the Column 'PartNumbers', however:

-->For EACH unique PartNumber, I want to select the specific ROW from that table that has the MAX VALUE of the 'PO' Column for that particular part number.

-->Also, to make life more difficult, I want to exclude the ANY of the PartNumbers who have ANY VALUE in the Column 'Receipt'

You guys have been a great help!  Much appreciated everyone!

EDIT:

Table Name: Log

Columns: ID, Supplier, PartNumber, PO, Quantity, DateReceived

Note: only the ID column is unique.

Comment: what is the difference v.s. previus answer?

Comment: The previous answer will select the Max value of the PO column (with all of the other requirements), however it will not select the rest of the data that goes along with that row.

Comment: Please provide schema (CREATE TABLE or DECLARE @t TABLE), sample data (INSERT), and desired results. This site is for solving programming problems, not word problems. :-)

Comment: Rest of data? Data is aggregate by PartNumber! What means rest of data? The data that has Max(PO) ?

Comment: Sorry, the 'rest of the data' refers to any other column of the ROW that has the max value of the PO for that particular PartNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CTE:

```
with TableWithRowNumber as
    (select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by PartNumber order by PO desc) as RowNo
    from MyTable)   
select * from TableWithRowNumber 
where RowNo = 1
and PartNumber not in 
    (select distinct PartNumber from MyTable where Receipt is not null)
```